# Adding datasource to excel combobox

Tags: excel, combobox

I would like to ask on how can I attach a datasource to combobox... is this possible without using VBA? My colleague gave me a template to pattern my requirements but as I observed, the data required by the combobox is located on a separate sheet. I just can't find how to attached that data source..

here is the example:
[screenshot from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cerLJ.png)

I have tried to use the active x controls and other but can't find on how to attach a data source...

Im hoping for someone to put me in a right direction.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

**Please See Thee Screenshot Clear Mention
1 Left Click Combo box Format Control Select Range Of data Source  **

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @jahanzaib, Thanks for the input! Im gonna try that. But i was wondering why the combobox on the template doesn't have a format tab... Is this other kind of control?

Comment: @Monsur MonPaulo  Pick Combo box In Form Control Don't Pick Active X Control I Send Screenshoot

Comment: Hi @jahanzaib, How can I create a datasource for this control? What im required to do is use another excel sheet to be a datasource... It has multiple column and values... is this possible?

Comment: Send Screenshoot To Your Data